# How can I let a classmate know I can't help them on an assignment anymore?

Tags: conflict-aversion, politeness, india, helping, students

I'm enrolled in a university course. For some time, I've been helping another student with a major project for our class, which counts for a quarter of our grade. It is an individual project where each person is expected to turn in their own work, but our teacher allows us to help each other out.

However, I no longer wish to work with them on the assignment. The first reason is a lack of time on my part: I have a part-time job, I have to do my own project, and I also have to write a large paper as an alternative assignment as I'll be missing the class final exam due to a conflict.

Additionally, just yesterday, the student was caught copying answers during our mid-term exam. (The exam was earlier, but it wasn't until yesterday that they were told about it.) The teacher has allowed them to continue in the course, but they would receive a zero on the exam and an overall grade deduction. They've admitted to me about copying, and I don't feel like working with someone who cheated.

Third, it's pretty clear to me they will not pass without any help. If I'm to help them succeed, I have to describe the concepts we're learning pretty much all over again repeatedly. This takes an emotional drag on me and detracts from my above other things.

Finally, the more I help him on the project, the greater the chance I will be called out for cheating because our work is similar. Given the classmate's prior record of cheating, it's likely the teacher will give their work extra scrutiny.

Prior to receiving the latest news (about the instructor allowing them to continue), I told them I have to help someone else on the assignment as well. This other classmate is much easier to work with, knows their concepts, and just needs help with fine-tuning. I also told them I have to help a third student with a project for another class, but I plan to instead put that student in contact with a tutor friend of mine.

After the first classmate received the news, they called me begging to help them on the project. I gave them a non-committal answer and it's right after that that I'm posting this question.

**How can I tell my classmate that I don't wish to help them on the project anymore, for the reasons outlined here?**

I found the answers at [How can I politely refuse to help classmates with their work?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/12043/11936), but they don't really work for me. First, this is from an Indian cultural context (we're in the U.S. but they're an Indian international student which forms a large part of the student body here), so the answers which say to stand for individuality won't work here: if I flatly deny, word of that will spread like wildfire and it may reflect negatively on me. **Already a couple other students here are asking me why I'm not helping the first student.** Second, the context there is that the student doesn't want to help anyone; I'm OK with helping, but just not that student. Many solutions there would be hypocritical since I agree to help someone else.

Comment: What about just telling the truth like you explain it here to us? I mean, 1. You have too much work and 2. You fear that the cheating might affect you. Your points are more than valid, why do you think it would backfire badly?

Comment: @OldPadawan The last paragraph addresses your points.

Comment: You have already helped them. Did that come with an explicit promise to help them through the entire project? Or have you just agreed with them to help with some smaller tasks/bits, one at a time? Also, if you have to prioritize, would you rather have the bad reputation from declining to help this student, or the bad reputation gained from being called out for cheating?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell To your first question, it's the latter. To your second question, the former.

Comment: When someone asks why you aren't helping the first student, and you point out that you **are** helping several other students and have limited time, why not ask the asker why **they** aren't helping the first student?

Comment: If you agreed to help someone else then you didn’t agree to help two people, so helping only one person is not hypocritical. Plus, you have the right to be hypocritical when it’s better for you. Plus, you wouldn’t help anyone who accuses you of being hypocritical.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I no longer wish to work with them on the assignment. The first reason is a lack of time on my part: I have a part-time job, I have to do my own project, and I also have to write a large paper as an alternative assignment as I'll be missing the class final exam due to a conflict.

Hey [classmate], I'm too busy to help you out any longer due to my work, school, life schedule so good luck with the rest of the class.

Done. Everything else is irrelevant beyond your schedule not supporting it. If he continues to push the issue, then you can get deeper into not wanting to be part of someone who cheats and how this is an individual assignment and you feel like you are doing it for him, etc.

When I was taking an electronics class in college, we had to do a team project and one team member didn't contribute anything. Part of the final report was to create a work breakdown and list the participation for each team member. Since he did not participate, we listed him at 0%, knowing that he would fail the class. The professor asked us about this during our presentation and we affirmed that he did not contribute anything to the project. We didn't cause him to fail the class... he did. You don't own or need to feel any emotion about your classmate's performance. This is his grade, not yours. Be firm and walk away from him.